# Is it valid to use the algebra of limits backwards?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I'm aware that we can say that the limit of, for example, (f + g) at a is equal to the limit of f at a summed with the limit of g at a, given that these two limits exist, but is it true that...

assuming lim (f + g) at a exists, then lim f at a + lim g at a = lim(f + g). Or, is this nonsense, It's very late at night and I've spun myself into a web.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1/x^2$ and $g(x)=-1/x^2$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to additionally know that at least one of the individual limits exists.  For instance, let $f(x)$ be your favorite function such that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist, and let $g(x)=-f(x)$.  Then $f+g$ is identically $0$ so $\lim_{x\to a}(f+g)(x)=0$, but neither individual limit exists.

On the other hand, if you know that the limits of $f$ and $f+g$ (or $g$ and $f+g$) both exist, then the limit of $g$ must exist since $g=(f+g)+(-f)$, and so you get that the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum.